# C# determining text file names

Tags: c#, file, file-io

How could I change this to determine the text files in its directory itself?

```
string[] file = new string[] {
    "abc",
    "def",
    "file3"};
var files = (UInt16)file.Length;
for (UInt16 n = 0; n < files; n++)
{
    var streamReader =
        new System.IO.StreamReader(
            file[n] + ".txt");
    ...
    streamReader.Close();
    ...
}
```

Comment: If the answers below are not answering your question, then consider making your question clear. I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ribtoks, Tigran and Eren Ersönmez all provided correct answers quickly, having had no problem with the question. Whats more all of the answers to this question are correct and relevant. I'd recomend you message them and ask for advice with the subject and comprehension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\", "*.txt");
```

**Update** Some usage:

```
foreach (var filename in files)
{
    string allText = File.ReadAllText(filename);
    // or string[] lines = File.ReadLines(filename);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f)

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),"*.txt");
```

And if you want to include subdirectories:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),"*.txt",
    SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Answer (score 3):

Can use [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx), like this more or less

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"/*Parent directory*/", "*.txt");
```

If this is not what you're asking for , please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Try to post the Clear Question so that you will get the Correct answer .

If you want to get the all files of type "*.txt". Try this code

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("Path");
var allTextFiles = dir.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```